# Vpn connection breaks with hint "short read (-1): Message too long"

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I have duall access l2tp connection to internet through router and pptp connection to my company's local network. Network Manager connects succesfully to vpn, but when I try to get some resources from company's network(for examle, clone git repository or connect to jira's dashboard), vpn connection breaks up with message(from syslog):
`short read (-1): Message too long`
whereas connection to moinmoin wiki causing no errors.
Ubuntu version: 12.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this issue happens because of high MTU(Maximum Transmission Unit) value. So the fix is to Change the MTU value in the NetworkManager.

Open **System Settings** -> **Network**

Under "Wired" select options and change the MTU to some lower value

Alternate way to change this settings is by editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the line MTU value.

```
mtu some_value_here
```

Now restart the networking `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

To check the current MTU value use the command `/sbin/ifconfig` and look MTU in eth0

Comment: maybe I should check MTU in wlan0, because i'm using connecting through wifi?

Comment: This worked for me. Before it was on `automatic` (I guess this is something around `1500`). After setting it to `1000`, my connection was stable.

Comment: The same as @panmari. It was automatic and 1000 solved the problem.